# Github Linguist overrides with wildcard

Tags: git, github, gitattributes, github-linguist

I want to set some GitHub's Linguist overrides in my `.gitattributes` file, more specifically I want to remove some ".vb" files from being taken into an account for determining the language statistics:

```
Solution 1/Vb/My Project/AssemblyInfo.vb
Solution 1/Vb/My Project/Resources.Designer.vb
Solution 1/Vb/My Project/Settings.Designer.vb
Solution 2/Vb/My Project/AssemblyInfo.vb
Solution 2/Vb/My Project/Resources.Designer.vb
Solution 2/Vb/My Project/Settings.Designer.vb
...
```

It's mentioned [here](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-gitattributes) that we can:

> use standard git-style path matchers for the files you want to override

So I tried the followings, but they're not working:

```
*/*/My Project/*.vb linguist-generated=true

*/*/My[[:space:]]Project/*.vb linguist-generated=true

**/My Project/* linguist-generated=true

**/My[[:space:]]Project/* linguist-generated=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following path matches your files:

```
*/*/My?Project/*.vb linguist-generated
```

Note that this also works:

```
**/My?Project/*.vb linguist-generated
```

Unfortunately, [git does not support white space escaping in .gitattributes' paths](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/gitattributes-escape-character-td5701115.html). `[[:space:]]` is only for regular expressions (`wordRegex`). `?` will match any character and not only spaces, but it might be enough in your case.